# Background Image not loading on server

Tags: html, css, iis-7.5

Just moved my project from my machine to our DEV server and I cannot get the background image to load. I've navigated to the url of the image (http://domain.sitename.com/Images/imagename.jpg) and there the image loads fine. I've also checked the security on the folder and can see both the IIS user group and the service account we're using for the site. Since I'm a complete n00b when it comes to CSS, I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere in there but I haven't been able to find a configuration that works. At this point would appreciate any leads/directions/hints/tips for figuring this out.

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
html {      
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-image: url('Images/Swiftnet-Background.jpg');
    color:#444444;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

Here's a screen shot of our folder structure

[image]

Comment: Is your css file inside your main root folder, from that css file can you navigate to Images/ directly or do you have to go back a folder?

Comment: The CSS file is in the "Content" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any url you reference, unless it is a full http url, will be relative to where the css file resides.  If your css is in root/Content, then your image folder must be in root/Content/Images.  If Images is actually back one folder, then you need to change your css url's to be url("../Images/imagename.jpg") instead.

Notice the two dots before "/Images" in the url, two dots means go back one folder.  If you need to go back two folders, then use "../../Images" etc.

Answer (score 0):

What Lochemage has said seems to be the only problem that I could find!
Ensure you upload your image in a folder named "Images" in your cPanel File Manager. 
The index.html can simply be uploaded on the first page.

Then create a folder named "Images" and upload your image with the same name, 
Siftnet-Background.jpg, into the folder.

Comment: Just uploaded a screen shot of the folder structure. The CSS file is in "Images", does the `url` look alright?

Comment: Hey Neal. What the code is computing at this time is that there is an folder named "Images" in the "Content" folder, and is looking for the Images there. Trying moving that folder into the "Content" folder and it should work!